# Adding custom attributes to SAML Assertion

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, saml-2.0, openam

After searching for a long time on the Internet, I have decided to post my question. I have to add a custom attribute and its value (in my case, a client contract number) to a SAML response object and send it to the SP. Below see the contract number attribute called "POLICE" inside the SP metadata:

```
<md:SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:AssertionConsumerService index="0" Location="POST_url_of_the saml_Response" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" isDefault="true"/>
    <md:AttributeConsumingService index="0">
        <md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">AttributeContract</md:ServiceName>
        <md:RequestedAttribute Name="ROLES"/>
        <md:RequestedAttribute Name="POLICE"/>
    </md:AttributeConsumingService>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
```

How can I use OpenAM SAML services to create a hyperlink within my web application?
I have OpenAM 10 as IDP.

Comment: You are being to unclear. You want to send a attribute to the SP. But was is this hyperlink got to do with it?

Comment: Thanks Stefan
after a user is authenticated through my sso server (idp), he have some link in my web application  to view some informations about his contract number.
 The contract number(numeric) should be the attribute "POLICE" (see the sp metadata above ).
 The contract number is an ressource hosted by the sp.
 How can I customize my link to include the contract number inside my Saml response ?

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

In OpenAM console select the SP, tab Federation , tab 'SP', subtab 'Assertion Procession', configure profile attribute to SAML attribute assertion mapping.

Make sure the profile attribute is configured in the data store config.

Comment: Hello Bernhard,  thanks for answer but my attribute is not coming from datastore, 
my attribute is the variable "POLICE (look sp metadata above)"  containing the contract number which is 
an ressource hosted by the sp. How can I build my SAML Assertion with contract number using openam rest api for example.
Thanks !!

Comment: You need to build a custom attribute matter to include the attributes into the assertion (http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/apidocs/index.html). However you would need to use OpenAM service management API to retrieve SAML metadata as I'm not aware of a public API to retrieve SAML metadata

non-public API could be
SAMLUtils.g
SAML2MetaManager

Comment: SAMLUtils.getSAML2MetaManager()
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityDescriptor(String realm,
        String entityId) to retrieve standard meta data
SAML2MetaManager.getEntityConfig(String realm, String entityId) to retrieve extended meta data

Comment: Hello Bernhard, thanks much for your time. I'm new to saml2. Should I build a custom attribute matter inside a Servlet filters using SAMLUils? How to send my custom saml response to sp ? please, may you give me some piece of code ?
thanks again !!!

Comment: It seems the steps are missing from dev-guide... need to file a doc-bug then.

You have to implement http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/apidocs/com/sun/identity/saml/plugins/AttributeMapper.html, add the class to OpenAM war and configure your own class as 'Attribute Mapper' instead of the default one (entity meta data)

Comment: Thanks again Bernhard for your time. After creating my custom class (AttributeMapper), how to set dynamically the value of requested attribute inside my saml response and send it to sp.

Comment: My requested attribute inside my saml response should look like this:
<saml:AttributeStatement>
   <saml:Attribute Name="POLICE" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
   </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a client contract number.
 thanks again !!!